# What are some good "Mac themes" for XP?

Tags: windows-xp, themes, skin

I want to install a Mac theme in XP.  I've tried several transformation packs without success.  Any advice on how I can do that or recommendations for good Mac or Mac-like themes?

Comment: Could you please edit that question into something more readable?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I actually think it's not even possible get an OS X-like Windows XP theme without using transformation packs.

> Windows XP has the ability to use
>   “visual styles” that use a *.msstyles
>   file on your hard drive.
>   Unfortunately, Microsoft didn’t set up
>   Windows XP to allow others to create
>   them. The code name for the “Windows
>   XP style” was "Luna" when XP was
>   developed. If you look in your
>   “C:\WINDOWS\Resources\Themes\Luna”
>   folder, you will find a file called
>   "Luna.msstyles". This is the "skin"
>   that is known as the "Windows XP
>   style".

I don't think the *.msstyles file alone can give you everything you want. I would resort to a transformation pack that has been tested by a more renowned website or that can be easily restored. Here are some guides you could follow to get some nice results:

- [Transform Windows XP into Mac Os Leopard without using Customization Pack](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ts0cP.jpg)

[image]

- [Desktop Visual Styles -- UXTheme Multi-Patcher](http://georgeh123.blogspot.com/2005/11/desktop-visual-styles-uxtheme-multi.html)

[image]

- [Windows XP Theme to transform to Mac OS X with Flyakite](http://techblissonline.com/windows-xp-theme-mac-osx/)

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Check out this [SU thread](https://superuser.com/questions/18716/making-switching-between-mac-and-pc-each-day-easier).  It's not perfect, but it's on point for changing XP look and feel to Mac (as much as possible, I guess :)

Answer (score 1):

[CrystalXP.Net](http://www.crystalxp.net/galerie/en.cat.3.html) has many "Visual Styles" for XP.