# Power user switching between Windows, Linux, and OSX - Need easier way to map Keyboard

Tags: linux, windows, macos, keyboard

Alright, I know this question has similar questions.  I went ahead and copied some below.  I am not interested in why I should learn Mac instead of Windows nor how to remap keys (It doesn't work very cleanly using the native methods)

What I want is my cake and to eat it too.  I want a way to set a profile to a particular keyboard and have mappings be set for all of the applications I use, especially text editors and others that have their own bindings.

I know this isn't the first nor last time this question will be asked, so I am politely asking for the best answer that beats all answers before it - a super easy macro type answer that fixes everything for 90% of everyone that comes across it.  I don't have much bounty to offer here but I will do what I can...

[Making switching between Mac and PC each day easier](https://superuser.com/questions/18716/making-switching-between-mac-and-pc-each-day-easier)

Comment: Is it just for particular keys (like Ctrl, or the Apple key), or do you have some internationalization that needs to be accounted for?

Comment: No internationalization but simply updating the keys isn't covering all the scenarios.  I want a Windows keyboard hooked up to a Mac to WORK like a Windows / Linux keyboard.  End, shift + end, copy+paste, EVERYTHING : )

Comment: Look for a keyboard hardware having what you are asking.  Also remember that all OSen do NOT necessary supply the same functionality in the same way, thus you will most likely be frustrated.

Comment: Eh what?  I can't understand your comment.  Just looking for a single way to have my one mac book pro use my Windows keyboard appropriately...